# jQuery moving focus from input, tab out, click out, even leaving page etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have managed to crack this somewhat that when I enter a valid email, it will then send via ajax and save the result to the carts session. However, I want to make sure I cover all angels and not sure how. Here is the JS so far:

```
function validEmail(v) {
    var r = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return (v.match(r) == null) ? false : true;
}

$('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {

    var email = $(this).val();  
    if (validEmail(email)) {
        //alert('valid email');
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email' ), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': email
            },
            caching: true
        });         
    }

});
```

I want to cover if user tabs away, clicks outside on page, clicks back browser button, closes window, closes tab etc. So it always makes sure it saves the value. Any ideas?

Also I just noticed, if I click out it saves value (all good) but if I change again it wont. Need to do each and every time even after ajax request from before.

Comment: You can use window.onblur() to check whether the page is in focus or not.

Comment: will that cover all i mentioned? and how would i integrate that?